# Generating an irregular polygon buffer around a line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapping

I want to create a cartographic effect to represent a hiking trail. I thought that it may look cool to generate an irregular buffer around the line representing the trails so it looks more "natural".

I think it can be done with the Geometry Generator, as it can generate a simple buffer around the line, but I don't know if is possible to generate an irregular shape.

Does anyone have a clue? I am also open to other ideas to map hiking trails.

EDIT: Here is a (terrible) sketch of what I would like to do. 
[image]

Comment: Could you draw a sketch about the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

The variable distance buffer under vector geoprocessing tools might help. You would need to define the preferred distance for the buffer as in the attribute table for the hiking trail. It would be symmetric on either side of the trail, but you could have variable width down the length of the trail.